# MySQL force replace to work with collation

Tags: mysql

I have a query in SQL that looks more or less like this:

```
select replace('Hello World', 'World', '') -- Returns  Hello
```

Now I want to use same function with utf-8 characters like this:

```
 select replace('Hello Wórld', 'World', '') -- Should Return Hello, but returns Hello Wórld
```

Note that I already have the collation set to utf-8 case insesitive;

following query returns true:

```
select 'ó' = 'o' -- Returns 1
```

Is there a quick way to make REPLACE function work as I expect?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I´m posting the real piece of code where I build the query, I didn´t think that it could help, but anyway, here it is:

```
...
self::$sql.="
        0";
        foreach ( $fields as $field=>$weight) { 

            foreach ( $keywords as $keyword ) { 
                self::$sql.="
                +COALESCE((LENGTH($table.$field) - LENGTH(REPLACE(LOWER($table.$field), LOWER('$keyword'), '')) )
                *$weight/LENGTH('$keyword'), 0)
                *COALESCE((LENGTH($table.$field) - LOCATE('$keyword', $table.$field))/LENGTH($table.$field), 0)
            ";
        }
    }
    self::$sql.=" AS weight";
```

...

Comment: The docs say `Returns the string str with all occurrences of the string from_str replaced by the string to_str. REPLACE() performs a case-sensitive match when searching for from_str.` i would assume you need to lower case everything for it to work

Comment: Indeed, I do, the query I posted is a simpler version of the real one, that uses LOWER before REPLACE, and doesn´t work neither